# How can I improve performance of Direct3D when I'm writing to a single vertex buffer thousands of times per frame?

Tags: performance, graphics, direct3d, direct3d11

I am trying to write an OpenGL wrapper that will allow me to use all of my existing graphics code (written for OpenGL) and will route the OpenGL calls to Direct3D equivalents. This has worked surprisingly well so far, except performance is turning out to be quite a problem.

Now, I admit I am most likely using D3D in a way it was never designed. I am updating a single vertex buffer thousands of times per render loop. Every time I draw a "sprite" I send 4 vertices to the GPU with texture coordinates, etc and when the number of "sprites" on the screen at one time gets to around 1k to 1.5k, then the FPS of my app drops to below 10fps.

Using the VS2012 Performance Analysis (which is awesome, btw), I can see that the ID3D11DeviceContext->Draw method is taking up the bulk of the time:
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trHOr.png)

Is there some setting I'm not using correctly while setting up my vertex buffer, or during the draw method? Is it really, really bad to be using the same vertex buffer for all of my sprites? If so, what other options do I have that wouldn't drastically alter the architecture of my existing graphics code base (which are built around the OpenGL paradigm...send EVERYTHING to the GPU every frame!)

The biggest FPS killer in my game is when I'm displaying a lot of text on the screen. Each character is a textured quad, and each one requires a separate update to the vertex buffer and a separate call to Draw. If D3D or hardware doesn't like many calls to Draw, then how else can you draw a lot of text to the screen at one time?

Let me know if there is any more code you'd like to see to help me diagnose this problem.

Thanks!

Here's the hardware I'm running on:

- Core i7 @ 3.5GHz
- 16 gigs of RAM
- GeForce GTX 560 Ti

And here's the software I'm running:

- Windows 8 Release Preview
- VS 2012
- DirectX 11

Here is the draw method:

```
void OpenGL::Draw(const std::vector<OpenGLVertex>& vertices)
{
   auto matrix = *_matrices.top();
   _constantBufferData.view = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(matrix);
   _context->UpdateSubresource(_constantBuffer, 0, NULL, &_constantBufferData, 0, 0);

   _context->IASetInputLayout(_inputLayout);
   _context->VSSetShader(_vertexShader, nullptr, 0);
   _context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &_constantBuffer);

   D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY topology = D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP;
   ID3D11ShaderResourceView* texture = _textures[_currentTextureId];

   // Set shader texture resource in the pixel shader.
   _context->PSSetShader(_pixelShaderTexture, nullptr, 0);
   _context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);

   D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
   D3D11_MAP mapType = D3D11_MAP::D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD;
   auto hr = _context->Map(_vertexBuffer, 0, mapType, 0, &mappedResource);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      OpenGLVertex *pData = reinterpret_cast<OpenGLVertex *>(mappedResource.pData);
      memcpy(&(pData[_currentVertex]), &vertices[0], sizeof(OpenGLVertex) * vertices.size());
      _context->Unmap(_vertexBuffer, 0);
   }

   UINT stride = sizeof(OpenGLVertex);
   UINT offset = 0;
   _context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
   _context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(topology);
   _context->Draw(vertices.size(), _currentVertex);
   _currentVertex += (int)vertices.size();
}
```

And here is the method that creates the vertex buffer:

```
void OpenGL::CreateVertexBuffer()
{
   D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
   ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
   bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
   bd.ByteWidth = _maxVertices * sizeof(OpenGLVertex);
   bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
   bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_FLAG::D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
   bd.MiscFlags = 0;
   bd.StructureByteStride = 0;
   D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
   ZeroMemory(&initData, sizeof(initData));
   _device->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &_vertexBuffer);
}
```

Here is my vertex shader code:

```
cbuffer ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix model;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float3 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexShaderOutput main(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;
    float4 pos = float4(input.pos, 1.0f);

    // Transform the vertex position into projected space.
    pos = mul(pos, model);
    pos = mul(pos, view);
    pos = mul(pos, projection);
    output.pos = pos;

    // Pass through the color without modification.
    output.color = input.color;
    output.tex = input.tex;

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is batch vertexes as aggressively as possible, then draw in large chunks. I've had very good luck retrofitting this into old immediate-mode OpenGL games. Unfortunately, it's kind of a pain to do.

The simplest conceptual solution is to use some sort of device state (which you're probably tracking already) to create a unique stamp for a particular set of vertexes. Something like blend modes and bound textures is a good set. If you can find a fast hashing algorithm to run on the struct that's in, you can store it pretty efficiently.

Next, you need to do the vertex caching. There are two ways to handle that, both with advantages. The most aggressive, most complicated, and in the case of many sets of vertexes with similar properties, most efficient is to make a struct of device states, allocate a large (say 4KB) buffer, and proceed to store vertexes with matching states in that array. You can then dump the entire array into a vertex buffer at the end of the frame, and draw chunks of the buffer (to recreate original order). Keeping track of all the buffer and state and order is difficult, however.

The simpler method, which can provide a good bit of caching under good circumstances, is to cache vertexes in a large buffer until device state changes. At that point, *prior to actually changing state*, dump the array into a vertex buffer and draw. Then reset the array index, commit state changes, and go again.

If your application has large numbers of similar vertexes, which is very possible working with sprites (texture coordinates and colors may change, but good sprites will use a single texture atlas and few blending modes), even the second method can give some performance boosts.

The trick here is to build up a cache in system memory, preferably a large chunk of pre-allocated memory, then dump it to video memory just prior to drawing. This allows you to perform far fewer writes to video memory and draw calls, which tend to be expensive (especially together). As you've seen, the number of calls you make gets to be slow, and batching stands a good chance of helping with that. The trick is to not allocate memory each frame if you can help it, batch large enough chunks to be worthwhile, and maintain correct device state and order for each draw.

Comment: I just added the vertex shader I'm using too. Notice that I'm multiplying each vertex by the model-view-projection matrices. If I move towards a batch algorithm like you suggest, would I have to multiply these vertices in my application code, before they are sent to the GPU and VS?

Comment: That depends on how long they last. If one of the matrices is changing every draw (you're translating sprites), then you may want to consider premultiplying; just the state changes you cut out could be a performance boost. If they change rarely, then just make them part of the batch and end/draw the batch when the matrices change.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand. Thanks for the answer. I'm working on this now, I'll let you know how it goes. If the batching really improves performance I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. Storing the vertices in a buffer and then blitting them all at once when the state changes has given a tremendous performance boost. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! How much of a boost did you end up getting, out of curiosity? It seems that playing with buffer/batch size and how much state you keep with the batch can influence it some, with larger buffers typically giving better performance. Even with relatively small buffers, there's a chance of getting decent performance.

Comment: The biggest improvement was one screen that was calling DeviceContext->Draw 350 times per frame and was running at 20FPS. With the batching, the draw count was reduced to 3 times per frame and now runs at 60FPS (maxed out).

Comment: There was another screen that was calling Draw 1144 times per frame and ran at below 7FPS. It was reduced to 21 calls to Draw and now runs at 24FPS which is not great, but the performance problem is now in my application code and not in D3D11.

Comment: Ha, compiling in release mode pushes that same screen from 24FPS to 60FPS (maxed out).

Comment: That's really good, a bit better than I've seen before. Seems like sprites are a very good case for batching like this; I'm going to have to go back through some old code of mine and see if I can't improve it. Glad this helped!

Comment: Whoops, just realized I had not assigned the bounty yet. I have now, it's yours. Thanks for the answer.