# How can I update buffers without drawing each time in DirectX

Tags: c++, graph, graphics, directx-11, scatter

I'm getting started with Direct3D 11 to create a simple application with quite some performance requirement. There are some concepts that confuses me.

Are buffer updates and drawing both part of the rendering loop? And is the rate of the render loop the rate of the frame, i.e. fps?

Since I'm practically trying to draw a scattering plot, I need to update the buffer at a very high rate, so I would avoid drawing the whole thing(or maybe I would avoid the part of rendering pipeline after Input Assembler) each time I read a point data.

What is controlling the rendering rate, the buffer update rate, and the fps?
Do I need to use separate threads? And how do people usually do for scattering plots?

Thanks a lot

I've post a similar question on gamedev
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131613/how-do-i-draw-a-high-performanced-scatter-plot
And a similar but not same question here
[How can I improve performance of Direct3D when I'm writing to a single vertex buffer thousands of times per frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117287/how-can-i-improve-performance-of-direct3d-when-im-writing-to-a-single-vertex-bu)

Comment: You control the rendering rate by publishing changes and presenting the scene.  You do it whenever you want.

Comment: And how is that gonna do with frame rate? What are the code that represent drawing on screen? Does the publishing changes and presenting the scene take a lot of time?

Comment: If you're making a small change to a vertex buffer per frame, you might want to have two vertex buffers and ping-pong between them, so you're not modifying the buffer you're trying to render that frame.  I mean you can do that but the driver has the headache of making sure it works.

Comment: Ah, that's a much better explanation! Very inspiring! Thank you. And I wonder where I can get more info about how this can work, the ping-pong thing?